# Storing duplicate html-tags in python dictionary while scraping beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, html, dictionary, tags, duplicates

I am scraping a website with BeautifulSoup4 using Python 3.6. Some content of the page looks like this:

```
<div class="contentContainer">
    <p class="contentLabel">Slaapkamer</p>
    <span class="contentValue">8 m²</span>
</div>
<div class="contentContainer">
    <p class="contentLabel">Slaapkamer</p>
    <span class="contentValue">7 m²</span>
</div>
```

The data has to go into a MySQL database so i am storing the values in a dictionary by

```
label = item.find('p', {'class': 'contentLabel'})
value = item.find('span', {'class': "contentValue"})
dictionary[label] = value
```

The problem i encounter, like in the example above is that the content label is used multiple times on the page.

Preferably i want the dictionary keys to increment if the label occurs multiple times on that page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary that stores a list of the content values:

```
label = item.find('p', {'class': 'contentLabel'}).text
dictionary[label] = [i.text for i in item.findAll('span', {'class': "contentValue"})]
```

Output:

```
{u'Slaapkamer': [u'8 m\xb2', u'7 m\xb2']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but that still won't work because i want to have the different values in different columns in the database.

I was able to resolve the problem by creating a second dictionary that counts the number of times a label occurs. From this dict I add the count after the name of the label

```
if label not in count_dict:
    count_dict[label] = 1
    dict[label] = value
else:
    count_dict[label] += 1
    label = label + ' ' + str(count_dict[label])
    dict[label] = value
```

Resulting output:

```
{
    'slaapkamer': '8 m²',
    'slaapkamer 2': '7 m²'
}
```